# Convert date isoString "2022-12-20T21:20:23.500Z" to format DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm in Athena sql

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, replace, casting, amazon-athena

[This is my actual date data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EV4m.png)

I would like to know if someone has the knowledge or knows how to format this date as mentioned in the title, I have already tried too many things, but I cannot solve it.
I would appreciate your help or contribution

2022-12-20T21:20:23.500Z -> 20/12/2022 21:20

Update:
if it helps anyone then i did this:

```
date_format( from_iso8601_timestamp('2009-10-30T17:59:55.047) at time zone 'UTC', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') as expiredate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ISO 8601 timestamp format.
Please first check data type then if it `string` you can convert it to `date` by

```
select from_iso8601_timestamp('2009-10-30T17:59:55.047') from mytable
```

> https://queirozf.com/entries/presto-athena-examples-date-and-datetime-functions#convert-string-to-datetime-iso-8601-timestamp-format

Then you convert `date` datetype to any format you want